# C# buffered GZipStream compression

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm writing a `database` backup function, reading from a `System.Diagnostics.Process object`, from `StandardOutput (StreamReader)` Property. I have succeeded in writing to plain file.

```
//This code successfully wrote text files.
StreamWriter f = new StreamWriter(BackupPath);
while (true) {
  //RaiseProgressedEvent(new DBProgressEventArgs(dbsize, progress, "Writing backup file"));

  int buffsize = 512;
  char[] buff = new char[buffsize];
  int count = p.StandardOutput.ReadBlock(buff, 0, buff.Length);
  if (count == 0) break;
  // If no more data, trim the char array
  if (p.StandardOutput.Peek() < 0) buff = (from c in buff where c > 0 select c).ToArray();

  f.Write(buff, 0, count);
  progress += buffsize;
}
f.Close();
```

But when i change to `GZipStream`:

```
//This code yields a broken gzip file.
//*2 lines changed: StreamWriter changed into FileStream.
FileStream fs = File.Create(BackupPath);
GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(fs, CompressionMode.Compress, true);

while (true) {
  RaiseProgressedEvent(new DBProgressEventArgs(dbsize, progress, "Writing backup file"));

  int buffsize = 512;
  char[] buff = new char[buffsize];
  int count = p.StandardOutput.ReadBlock(buff, 0, buff.Length);
  if (count == 0) break;
  if (p.StandardOutput.Peek() < 0) buff = (from c in buff where c > 0 select c).ToArray();

  //With UTF 8 Encoding, write to gzipstream.
  //f.write changed into the following 2 lines:
  Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF8;
  zipStream.Write(enc.GetBytes(buff), 0, enc.GetByteCount(buff));

  progress += buffsize;
}
fs.Close();
```

The resulting `GZip` file is incomplete/broken. When decompressed with `7zip` and then opened with `notepad++`, almost all the text is good, only some bytes near the ending of the file are lost. I am not sure, but perhaps the error is near: `zipStream.Write(enc.GetBytes(buff), 0, enc.GetByteCount(buff));`
Perhaps something to do with the `enc.GetByteCount(buff)`.

The reading is buffered for multithreading, for handling large files. So... why did the last bytes are lost? Where did i do wrong?

Comment: What's suspicious is that you're never closing/disposing your `zipStream`. It's possible it's not necessary, but it's the first thing I'd try.

Comment: Yes, you're closing some `fs` which is not shown, but is probably the underlying file stream. You can't close that without letting the GZipStream finish its work. Always close the last one, not the first one in the chain.

Comment: fs is the FileStream at the top of the code snippet.

Comment: @hvd yep... it solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Use the constructor of `GZipStream` to Close the Stream post `Dispose` of the `GZipStream`. 
`GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(fs, CompressionMode.Compress, false);`
Preferable enclose both `FileStream` and `GZipStream` in the using block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

- Use a constructor of `GZipStream`, which close the `FileStream` post `Dispose`

  ```
  using(FileStream fs = File.Create(BackupPath))
  using(GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(fs, CompressionMode.Compress, false))
  {

   while (true) {
    RaiseProgressedEvent(new DBProgressEventArgs(dbsize, progress, "Writing backup file"));

   int buffsize = 512;
   char[] buff = new char[buffsize];
   int count = p.StandardOutput.ReadBlock(buff, 0, buff.Length);
   if (count == 0) break;
   if (p.StandardOutput.Peek() < 0) buff = (from c in buff where c > 0 select c).ToArray();

   //With UTF 8 Encoding, write to gzipstream.
   //f.write changed into the following 2 lines:
   Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF8;
   zipStream.Write(enc.GetBytes(buff), 0, enc.GetByteCount(buff));

   progress += buffsize;
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: @hvd comment above (closing the zipstream) solved the problem. But this answer also solved the problem. And somehow this code is neater. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is Zip the file in same folder then I try the code below is working.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"F:\Harris\abc.txt");
            FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"F:\Harris\abc.txt");
            using (FileStream compressedFileStream = File.Create(fi.FullName + ".gz"))
            {
                using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream,
                System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress, true))
                {
                    fs.CopyTo(compressionStream);
                }
            }//end using

            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally { }
    }
```